# convert data frame of counts to proportions by conditions in R

Tags: r, apply

I would need to expand on this question: [convert data frame of counts to proportions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503580/convert-data-frame-of-counts-to-proportions-in-r)

I need to calculate proportion by one condition and retain the information of the dataset.

Reproducible example:

```
ID <- rep(c(1,2,3), each=3)
trial <- rep("a", 9)
variable1 <- sample(1:10, 9)
variable2 <- sample(1:10, 9)
variable3 <- sample(1:10, 9)
condition <- rep(c("i","j","k"), 3)
dat <- data.frame(cbind(ID, trial,variable1,variable2,variable3,condition))
```

For each variable I would like to have the proportion by the ID (i.e. 3 times)
Ideally the new variables would be stored in the same database as `dat$variable1_p`

I know how to do the trick by a series of for loops but I would like to learn how to use the apply function. Also to be able to expand it to more conditions if necessary.

Comment: It would be useful to know the reason for the downvote, so that I can improve my style of asking questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `adply` from the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
adply(dat, 1, function(x)
    c('variable1_p' = x$variable1 / sum(dat[x$ID == dat$ID,]$variable1)))

#   ID trial variable1 variable2 variable3 condition variable1_p
# 1  1     a         3         5         4         i  0.20000000
# 2  1     a         8         9         9         j  0.53333333
# 3  1     a         4         4         8         k  0.26666667
# 4  2     a         7        10         5         i  0.50000000
# 5  2     a         6         8        10         j  0.42857143
# 6  2     a         1         1         7         k  0.07142857
# 7  3     a        10         6         3         i  0.47619048
# 8  3     a         9         7         6         j  0.42857143
# 9  3     a         2         3         2         k  0.09523810
```

Another option is to use `dplyr`, which would handle cases where there is more than one row per condition per ID:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(ID, condition) %>%
    mutate(sum_v1_cond = sum(variable1)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(variable1_p = sum_v1_cond / sum(variable1)) %>%
    select(-sum_v1_cond)
```

#### Edit - here's a full solution for `variable1`, `variable2`, and `variable3`:

```
adply(dat, 1, function(x)
    c('variable1_p' = x$variable1 / sum(dat[x$ID == dat$ID,]$variable1),
      'variable2_p' = x$variable2 / sum(dat[x$ID == dat$ID,]$variable2),
      'variable3_p' = x$variable3 / sum(dat[x$ID == dat$ID,]$variable3)))
```

#### Data:

```
set.seed(123)
ID <- rep(c(1,2,3), each=3)
trial <- rep("a", 9)
variable1 <- sample(1:10, 9)
variable2 <- sample(1:10, 9)
variable3 <- sample(1:10, 9)
condition <- rep(c("i","j","k"), 3)
dat <- data.frame(ID, trial,variable1,variable2,variable3,condition,
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful tips, however the result showed is not the one I was looking for. The first 3 values of `variable1_p` would need to be (in your example): 0.0526; 0.5263; 0.4210. Which are the proportions for the condition i, j, k of the ID=="1".

Comment: @havefun I misunderstood your question, I will be editing shortly :)

Comment: @havefun Will there ever be an ID which has more than one row per condition?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, I don't think so. The dataset has that structure repeated over and over.

Comment: @havefun For example, in row 1 we see that `ID = 1` has `condition = i`, would it ever be possible to have another row where `ID = 1` and `condition = i`? If not, the `adply` solution from `plyr` should work smoothly for you.

Comment: No, there will only be that ID. Thanks a lot for your help. I will study your strategy.